# IOS5 IOS 5 (9A334) iPhone 4 XCode 4.2 4D199 Lion 10.7.2 Instruments 4.2 (4233) Not Working

Tags: xcode, ios5, instruments, osx-lion

Can not seem to get an iPhone 4 with IOS 5 connecting to instruments.  Tried from XCODE Profile and Attaching to Process with no luck.  Anyone else seen this?

Same setup works fine with IOS 4.2.1

But, does the same thing (does not work) with IOS 4.3.5 (8L1)

Build target is 4.2, no change if build target changes...

Need to do some run time performance analysis.

Comment: FYI, woking fine with iPad 4.3.2 and iPad 4.3.5

Comment: Not sure why the edits are happening when you don't work for the web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to hard stop the Instruments tool after every run for some reason.  Then will work fine from XCODE / PRODUCT / PROFILE.  At least on this setup.